# Android: How to switch between 2 ImageView using fade in and fade out

Tags: android, imageview, fadein

I'm trying to perform an alpha animation between two images by clicking on each of them, but when I click on the first image nothing happens.

I set alpha for `spotlight view` so that it will be always invisible.

Here is my function I wrote in Java:

```
public void fade_1(View view) {
    ImageView revenant = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.revenant);
    ImageView spotlight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spotlight);

    revenant.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    spotlight.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}

public void fade_2(View view) {

    ImageView spotlight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spotlight);
    ImageView revenant = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.revenant);

    spotlight.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    revenant.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```